# Pending Status in Network when trying to Create new entry in table

Tags: reactjs, express, jwt, axios, passport.js

Trying to add new data a recipe to the table 'recipes'.

console.log(data) and console.log(req.body) gives me the values I input and sent to the backend, but it's not writing it to the table & on Network in the chrome console I am getting a PENDING Status

CREATE recipe in the backend index.js__

```
  api.post('/recipe', passport.authenticate('jwt', {
    session: false
  }), (req, res) => {
        const data = {
          recipe_name: req.body.name,
          recipe_meal: req.body.meal,
          recipe_author: req.body.author,
          recipe_description: req.body.description,
          recipe_ingredients: req.body.ingredients,
          recipe_preparation: req.body.preparation
        }
    console.log(req.body)
    db.query('INSERT INTO recipes SET ?', [data], (err, results) => {
            console.log(data)
      if (err) {
        res.status(500)
        return;
      }
      db.query('SELECT * FROM recipes', (err, rows) => {
        if (err) {
          res.status(500)
          return;
        }
        res.json({
          recipes: rows
        });
      })
    })
  });
```

CREATE recipe in the frontend Profile.js__

```
handleCreate(){
   const jwt = localStorage.getItem('jwt')
   console.log(jwt)
   axios({
     method: 'post',
     data: {
      name: this.state.name,
      author: this.state.author,
      meal: this.state.meal,
      description: this.state.description,
      ingredients: this.state.ingredients,
      preparation: this.state.preparation
     },
     url: 'http://localhost:4000/api/recipe',
     headers: {
       'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + jwt
     }
   }).then((response) => {
     this.setState({ recipe: response.data });
     console.log(this)
   }).catch((error, res) => {
    if(error.response.status === 401) {
       console.log("Error:", error);
       alert("Failed")
     }
   })
 }
```

Example of the input fields:

```
<TextField helperText="Enter the name of your recipe" label="name" onChange = {(event) => this.setState({name: event.target.value})}/>
<Button color="secondary" onClick={(event) => this.handleCreate(event)}>Submit Recipe</Button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah me again - I don't know why it was pending, but I fixed the CREATE recipe, the INSERT statement.

In api/index.js this is what the data object has to look like.
If you look into the console.log(req.user) - you notice that it's sending the id, not the user_id in the req.user -- thus we have to say that the Foreign Key user_id is the id from user.

```
const data = {
  user_id: req.user.id,
  recipe_name: req.body.name,
  recipe_meal: req.body.meal,
  recipe_author: req.body.author,
  recipe_description: req.body.description,
  recipe_ingredients: req.body.ingredients,
  recipe_preparation: req.body.preparation
}
```

Also change this:

FROM::

```
db.query('SELECT * FROM recipes', (err, rows) => {
```

TO::

```
db.query('SELECT * FROM recipes WHERE user_id = ? ', [req.user.user_id], (err, 
rows) => {
```

I also added a page reload, on success (200).

```
if (response.status === 200) {
          console.log("Post Success");
          window.location.reload();
        }
```